# Access SQL - How can I filter a table based on what is written in a textbox in a form?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I recently stared using Microsoft Access and now I'm trying to display a query in a form depending on what is written in a textbox and then open that query by double clicking the row or cell that was filtered.

For example I have a table with named customers with a list of customers and I'm trying to find a customer by the name of (for example) Jhon by writing "Jhon" in the textbox and then by double clicking on that cell or row open only that row (using a query).

Table name is "Customers", Form name is "Form2", Subform (what I'm trying to sort/filter) name is "Custormers subform1", the name of the unbound textbox is "Search".

Here is what my form looks like : [http://imgur.com/a/DpQ7p](https://imgur.com/a/DpQ7p).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the search in the AfterUpdate event handler of the textbox and set the filter property of the subform

```
Private Sub Search_AfterUpdate()
    Dim s as string

    s = "'" & Replace(Me!Search.Text, "'", "''") & "'"
    Me![Custormers subform1].Form.Filter = "FirstName=" & s & " OR " LastName=" & s 
End Sub
```

Make sure to escape single apostrophs by double ones. You can also search by the beginning of a name with

```
    s = " LIKE '" & Replace(Me!Search.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
    Me![Custormers subform1].Form.Filter = "FirstName" & s & " OR " LastName" & s
```

The resulting filter then looks like (assuming the user typed "Jh")

```
FirstName LIKE 'Jh*' OR LastName LIKE 'Jh*'
```